# Creating a unit test suite using Rspec and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, sinatra, factory-bot

I have a requirement where we should be creating for Factories for servers, we call them as Vservers. It basically has the attributes like Fully qualified domain name (fqdn), eg: dev-vserver.storage.com, ID and etc..

We make a connection to the Vserver and retrieve information about different operations that we do like provisioning storage, resizing of volumes, deletion of volumes etc., in a json format.

We would like to come up with a better unit testing environment with RSPEC and FactoryGirl, where we can mock the Vserver functionality by creating doubles or mocks instead of directly interacting with the actual Vserver for testing.

I would like to hear suggestions and opinions from all you.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

So from what I gather, you want to use mocks or test doubles to mimic the functionality of your Vservers. This is indeed possible, the question is *should* it be done.

You can use factory girl to create factories for each of your Vserver classes, but those facotories will only return whatever data you give them, they wont have any *real* data, since they only have whatever you assigned them in your tests or factories.

What I would recommend is that within your facotries, you actually establish a connection to each instance of your Vservers, and pull back all the attributes which you need. So for example you could create a factory like so:

```
factory :vserver_1 do
   id { connect_to_vserver_1_and_get_id }
   domain_name { connect_to_vserver_1_get_domain_name }
end
```

This would instantiate a new instance of vserver_1, with all the attributess of your current vserver. If you were to change the domain name of verserver 1 in the future, your vserver_1 factory would reflect these changes.

Also, the factory girl gem has great [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), you should definitely read them in their entirety before building a new test suite. Good luck!